# Python3 ElementTree loop stalls while parsing. Trace shows subprocess.CalledProcessError

Tags: python, python-3.x, elementtree

My experience is with HTML/CSS/PHP but I have recently started working with python. I find myself stuck and hope someone can spot what I am doing incorrectly. The program I am working on is stalling while retrieving some variables from an xml document. I have narrowed it down to this section:

(Made up the variables)

```
def add_ingredients_for_selected_recipes(self, root):
        recipes = ["Beef Stew", "Tuna Casserole", "Spaghetti", "Chocolate Cake"]
        guest = self.settings.get('guest')
        allergies = {'nuts': ["guest1", "guest2", "guest3"], 'seafood': ["guest5", "guest6"]}

        for recipe in recipes:
            # Add necessary ingredients for user desired recipes to our list
            if self.settings.get("recipe_" + recipe):
                self.queue_event('info', 'Selecting ingredients for "%s" recipe.' % recipe)
                for child in root.iter(recipe):
                    for ing in child.iter('ingredient'):
                        contains = ing.attrib.get('allergy')
                        if contains is None:
                            self.queue_event('debug', 'Adding ingredient:%s' % (ing.text))
                            self.ingredients.append(ing.text)
                        elif contains in allergies and guest in allergies[contains]:
                            self.queue_event('debug', 'Adding ingredient:%s contains %s' % (ing.text, contains))
                            self.ingredients.append(ing.text)
                        else:
                            self.queue_event('debug', 'Skipping ingredient:%s contains %s' % (ing.text, contains))
```

Here is what I grep'd from the trace: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/60521097/fromtrace
One more thing that's relevant is if I remove the portion that checks for the attribute it works fine. So I know where the problem is but I am not seeing it. Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: How is the stacktrace connected to your script?

Comment: I changed the variables in the example above but the stacktrace is unchanged. I did this so it wouldn't be connected to my project by any search engine bots.

Comment: You might want to break that up into smaller functions/methods so it's easier to debug. Every where you have a 'for' or an 'if/else' is a good candidate for separation. That will help the readability too.

Comment: If you find that your doing the same thing a lot in different areas of your code you might try decorators. Once those are debugged they can just be inserted where you need them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out the problem. I previously defined which "recipes" were available as option for each of the "guests". When the main loop (for recipe in recipes:) gets to a recipe that is not defined as an available option to the "allergy" in "allergies" it shows False and the loop can't continue. I fixed this by defining the "recipes" variable based on selected "guest" like this:

```
self.recipes_by_guest = {"guest1": ["Beef Stew", "Tuna Casserole", "Spaghetti"],
                        "guest2": ["Beef Stew", "Spaghetti"],...etc}
guest = self.settings.get("guest")
recipes = self.recipes_by_guest[guest]
allergies = {'nuts': ["guest1", "guest2", "guest3"], 'seafood': ["guest5", "guest6"]}

for recipe in recipes: etc...
```

Thanks to everyone who had a look and commented suggestions!